# The right mySQL syntax for multiple SELECT statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, aggregate-functions

I am trying to SELECT multiple columns with one SELECT statement and I tried it like this and didn't work.

```
mysql> SELECT AVG(salaryoffered) "$ offer" AS "Average Salary", MIN(salaryoffered)
"$ offer" AS "Min Salary", MAX(salaryoffered) "$ offer" AS "Max Salary" FROM
interview;
```

However, they did work and bring up the table with SELECT, individually. Like this:

```
mysql> SELECT AVG(salaryoffered) "$ offer" AS "Average Salary" 
mysql> SELECT MIN(salaryoffered) "$ offer" AS "Min Salary" 
mysql> SELECT MAX(salaryoffered) "$ offer" AS "Max Salary" 
    -> FROM interview;
```

Any idea how I can put the three tables together in one command?
Suppose to look like this:

```
+----------------+------------+------------+
| Average Salary | Min Salary | Max Salary |
+----------------+------------+------------+
|      12.080357 |      10.75 |      13.75 |
+----------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: are you sure this works? `SELECT AVG(salaryoffered) "$ offer" AS "Average Salary"`?

Comment: yes it works! I tried them all individually, they all work, but when put together, they don't. Hmm...

Comment: Get rid of `"$ offer"` in each expression.  That syntax is not right.  Without `"$ offer"` it should work fine.

Comment: no it shouldn't. it will throw syntax error. `AVG(salaryoffered) "$ offer"` is not right.

Answer (score 0):

The first query also wont work. try this.

```
SELECT AVG(salaryoffered) AS "Average Salary", 
MIN(salaryoffered) AS "Min Salary", 
MAX(salaryoffered) AS "Max Salary" 
FROM interview;
```

If you want to add some text, use concat, something like

```
SELECT concat(AVG(salaryoffered), "$ offered") AS "Average Salary", 
concat(MIN(salaryoffered), "$ offered") AS "Min Salary", 
concat(MAX(salaryoffered), "$ offered") AS "Max Salary" 
FROM interview;
```